# Is it safe to use a concurrenthashmap that is shared with 100K actors?

Tags: scala, akka

I have about 100K products that I want to keep in memory.
These products can change at a high rate per hour, but at the same time reads will be the majority of the calls, and there can be a delay with getting the most recent version.

I want to create 1 actor per product, but have a shared in-memory store of the product.

Is it safe to use a concurrenthashmap and pass it as a prop to 100K actors?

```
val products = new ConcurrentHashMap[ProductId, Product](initialCapacity)
```

So in my actor I will have something like:

```
def recieve = {
  case GetProduct(id: ProductId) =>
    // lookup in products concurrenthashmap, if not there, read from datastore and return 
    //
  case UpdateProduct(id: ProductId) => ???
}
```

When there are updates, there could be 100-500K per hour.  There can be a delay in the update, that's not an issue.   So to distribute the updates and prevent locks, 1 actor per product is what I am thinking.  I just want to make the cache global across all actors.

Is this design sound?

Comment: First of all, actors should not share the state. The keyword being "should", which means you can but only if really required. You can probably come up with an alternative design by sharding the key-space.

Answer (score 9):

ConcurrentHashMap is safe to be shared, the number of threads does not matter. But why do you create 100k actors when you keep the state elsewhere anyway? An Actor exists because it owns its state; if that is not the case then the Actor should not exist.

So either you keep your data in a ConcurrentHashMap, but then you need only as many threads (actors) as you have CPU cores to make the accesses. Or you ditch the CHM and store each of your products in its own designated Actor. The decision depends on the nature of the operations you want to perform: if you want to interact only with a single product at a time, then Actors are a great way of modelling that. If you want to interact with a collection of products at a time, then use something else.

Comment: Yes I will need to interact with a collection of products.  What do you mean by something else...meaning?

Comment: As I said, you could access a CHM; there are many tools out there, like (in memory) databases etc. It depends so much on the characteristics of your data and your access pattern that it is impossible for me to solve your design question, especially on StackOverflow.